# ng2-file-upload: Cannot read property 'queue' of undefined

Tags: angular

i am trying to use [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) library to upload files in the angular2, typescript.

`"@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1"`

So, first i

```
npm i ng2-file-upload --save
```

and changed the app.module.ts to the:

```
    import { FileUploadModule } from "ng2-file-upload";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    UploaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    FileUploadModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

in the component i have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';

// const URL = '/api/';
const URL = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-demo',
  templateUrl: './simple-demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple-demo.component.css']
})
export class SimpleDemoComponent {
  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

  public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

  public fileOverAnother(e:any):void {
    this.hasAnotherDropZoneOver = e;
  }
}
```

a part of the html side of component is:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
```

and it complains with:

```
 Cannot read property 'queue' of undefined
```

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/salman-/angular2-template)
just do a **npm install** and then **ng serve**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

Do you get the error when the page has loaded or when you try to upload a file?

If you are getting the error right after uploading a file please check "**onWhenAddingFileFailed**" event to see if it throws some kind of error.

You may find my code that works for me below:

```
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';

@NgModule({   
imports: [
    FileUploadModule
],
providers: [        
],
declarations: [MyTestComponent],   
    exports: []
})
```

>

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
```

>

```
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';
export class MyTestComponent implements OnInit {
    public uploader: FileUploader;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.uploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL });
        this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = () => this.onUploaderAfterAddingFile();  
        this.uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = () => this.onUploaderWhenAddingFileFailed();       
    }
}
```

If this doesn't help please put a break point to "**this.uploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL })**" part of the code and check what does "**this.uploader.queue**" returns.

Finally you may check **file.uploader.class.js** which can be found in "**/node_modules/ng2-file-upload/**" path to give you more info on how does "uploader.queue" object is initialized and filled.

Hopefully this would help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add the forms module to imports:

```
import { FileUploadModule } from "ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-upload.module";
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
imports: [FileUploadModule, FormsModule],
declarations: [AppComponent],
```

**Component**

```
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
```

Comment: You can get my code from here https://github.com/salman-/angular2-template

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is having a similar issue...
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null at FileSelectDirective".

after a little debugging i saw, that instead of this:

[image]

i got that:

[image]

My markup looked like this:

```
ng2FileDrop (fileOver)="setFileOver($event)" [attr.uploader]="uploader">
```

i dont know **WHEN** and **WHY** i did that. The [demo](https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/) says clearly this:

```
 <div ng2FileDrop
             [ngClass]="{'another-file-over-class': hasAnotherDropZoneOver}"
             (fileOver)="fileOverAnother($event)"
             [uploader]="uploader"
             class="well my-drop-zone">
            Another drop zone
        </div>
```

that solved my problem, so i got rid of the `attr`prefix, and everything worked fine.